# Get n-th bit of an integer

Tags: python

I am given a large integer `a`, and a (relatively small) integer `n`.

What is the fastest way to get the `n`th bit (from the right) of the binary representation of `a` using native Python?

Comment: @JohnMachin: `a` has about 1000 digits, `n` is about 1000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked for the *fastest* way, presumably using a modern version of Python. Modern versions of Python have variable-length ints, and conventional wisdom does't apply. Shifting a large number is not cheap. Shifting 1 is cheap. Here are some -mtimeit inputs and corresponding outputs. The first is an abbreviation of

```
windows command prompt>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"a=10**20;n=3" "(a>>n)&1"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.238 usec per loop

-s"a=10**20;n=3" "(a>>n)&1"
0.238 usec 

-s"a=10**20;n=3" "not not(a & (1 << n))"
0.154 usec 

-s"a=10**200;n=3" "(a>>n)&1"
0.382 usec 

-s"a=10**200;n=3" "not not(a & (1 << n))"
0.155 usec 

-s"a=10**10;n=3" "(a>>n)&1"
0.231 usec 

-s"a=10**10;n=3" "not not(a & (1 << n))"
0.156 usec 

-s"a=10**9;n=3" "(a>>n)&1"
0.0801 usec

-s"a=10**9;n=3" "not not(a & (1 << n))"
0.0938 usec

-s"a=2**1000;n=64" "(a>>n)&1"
0.446 usec

-s"a=2**1000;n=64" "not not(a & (1 << n))"
0.255 usec
```

If `not not(foo)` freaks you out, or you really want an `int` answer instead of a `bool`, you can use `1 if foo else 0`; it's only slightly slower.

Comment: Nice observation.  Just for the record, in Python 3.1 with the distinction between `long` and `int` removed, the straight-forward approach is also the fastest (at least on my machine).

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I get similar results with 2.7, 3.1, and 3.2 ... I'll do a fuller evaluation tonight; must rush off now ...

Comment: The complete [timings on my machine](https://gist.github.com/1839351) are indeed more differentiated than my previous comment suggests. (I did only some of your tests before, and happened to hit the ones where the straight-forward approach is faster.)

Answer (score 17):

Shift the bit to the last position, mask out everthing else:

```
bit = (a >> n) & 1
```

This assumes that the bits are indexed in the usual way, i.e. the least significant bit is bit 0.

**Edit**: I'm not sure if this is the *fastest* way to do it in your version of Python, but at least it is the most straight-forward way.  Depending on your Python version and the particular values of `a` and `n`, there might be faster ways, as shown in the [answer by John Machin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301005/279627).

Comment: -1 What gives you the impression that this is the fastest way, under what definitions of "large" and "relatively small"?

Comment: @JohnMachin: I could see from this question and from the other questions by the OP that the user did not know *at all* how to do it.  My interpretation of the question is that "the fastest" could just as well have been "the easiest" or "the best" or whatever.  In such a case I try to be helpful and explain the very basics.  If you really think that this answer is *not* helpful, then I'll have to accept that your notion of helpfulness is very different from mine.  (I think your answer and your way to read the question is perfectly valid as well.)

Comment: I can't remove the down vote until you edit your answer (perhaps to explain your definition of "fastest").